# What is the best way to add components to a java application

Tags: java, swing, components

Right now I create all of my  swing components in the same class that has my method "main", this class keeps growing and looking more unorganized with each component created. Should I create another class to create the components and pass a the frame by reference? Or should I let my current class keep growing? Is there a best practice or industry standard?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Isolate responsibility.  Create child components to encapsulate the view, allow access to models and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "it depends." If it is a simple UI, you can get away with one class. But if there are several independent windows or other components, consider creating separate classes. Then instantiate them in your main class.

For example, consider a banking application. There may be different windows for the different functions (withdraw, deposit, transfer, balance inquiry). You could have four different classes that extend JPanel. Then in your main class, you can instantiate these classes and assemble them.

Just a thought.